# Download a Byte Array as a File in Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some old web pages where a file is downloaded to the user. These pages worked when they were developed five or six years ago, but don't work now. My download code works on pageload, but I need to to work on postback as a button is clicked. That causes this error: "Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent."

I've found references saying to do this with an iframe. My source is a byte array created in the postback. I have not been able to find any examples of how to do this.

Can anyone point me to a reference?

This is the test page I'm using.

```
            public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            RadListBox1.Items.Clear();
        }
    }

    protected void RadButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ErrorOutput("Button pressed.");
        //DownloadToBrowser();
        Go();
    }


    protected void Go()
    {
        string fileName = "Drawing1.png";
        string orgPath = @"..\tempfiles\";
        string filePath = MapPath(Path.Combine(orgPath, fileName));
        byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        ErrorOutput(byteArray.Count() + " Bytes in the file.");
        System.Web.HttpResponse res = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
        Response.Flush();
    }    // Go() ...

    protected void ErrorOutput(string theError)
    {
        RadListBox1.Items.Add(theError);
    }


}    // class Test ...
```

Here is the HTML;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="KCNet2.Report.Test" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<h2>Download Test</h2>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"
    AssociatedUpdatePanelID="pnlPrint">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="progress">
            <img alt="" class="style1" src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            Processing...
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlPrint" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="RadButton1_Click" AutoPostBack="true"></telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBox1" runat="server"></telerik:RadListBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Comment: Terms like "pageload" and "postback" imply WebForms.  Is that the case here?  A WebForms post-back invokes `Page_Load` just like any other request.  It's not clear what specific problem you're trying to describe.  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate the specific debugging observations you have made.

Comment: In the above configuration I get the indicated error. If I run the Go() function in the pageload it will download the file, so I know the Go() function works. I need to be able to run the Go() function in a post back after clicking the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should work, and this works for me:

```
    protected void cmdDownLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filename = Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/Fighters/Add.png");
        string filenameONLY = Path.GetFileName(filename);

        byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
        // ErrorOutput(byteArray.Count() + " Bytes in the file.");
        // System.Web.HttpResponse res = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filenameONLY);
        Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
        Response.Flush();

    }
```

You can also use now this: (requires .net 4.5 or later).

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/Fighters/Add.png");
        string filenameONLY = Path.GetFileName(filename);
        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);

        FileInfo sFinfo = new FileInfo(filename);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", sFinfo.Length.ToString());

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filenameONLY);
        Response.TransmitFile(filename);
        Response.End();

    }
```

Both examples work, and work by simple click on a button, which of course is a post-back.

## Edit: The update panel issue

The issue is NOT the post-back, as above shows. The issue is that you can only have ONE response back, and that means you either download the file, OR you choose to update controls on the web page - you can't do both with above example.

I suspect your REAL question is can I update controls on the web form, AND THEN down load the file - a vast, huge and Mount Everest of a different question.

As a general rule, you find that a download does NOT work when placed inside of a update panel.

Comment: Any chance you have the answer to that Mount Everest of an issue?

Comment: No, I just don't have a good solution (my sorry). I never really found one either. You can google/search for "run JavaScript after file download", but its not all that easy.